# VirtualBox: importing virtual disk from one PC to a another PC

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Our server is broken and i need to import virtual disk from old server HDD to a new server.

But when i'm just selecting old hdd virtual disk to a newly created virtual PC it just stuck and gives some kind of error about UUID.

What should i do?

Thanks ;)

**Update**
Error screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/m/88/1121/erroret.png

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with VirtualBox. Other than the fact that VirtualBox caused the UUID to change when attaching to a new system. The same thing would most likely happen if this were a physical disk moved to another physical system. This is a normal Linux mount error when using UUIDs.
UUIDs can change for a number of reasons, installing to another partition on the same drive, cloning the disk, etc..

The easiest 3 fixes:

- attach and boot to a rescue live-cd iso on the broken system (the newly created virtual client).
- Mount root
- cat /etc/fstab  - look for the UUID for / or the mount point causing the error.
- reset the drives UUID - tune2fs /dev/sdXX -U UUID

or

- attach and boot to a rescue live-cd iso on the broken system
- Mount root
- cat /etc/fstab  - determine the mount point causing the error.
- determine current UUID  - ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
- edit fstab to the new current UUID

or

- attach and boot to a rescue live-cd iso on the broken system
- Mount root
- edit /etc/fstab  - determine the mount point causing the error, rewrite into the old format /dev/sdXX (or /dev/hdXX if still using IDE on older systems)

Tinycore and Puppy Linux make great small rescue cds with web browsing support. Use Knoppix or Trinity Rescue Kit for more features.

You can always attach the "broken" system's disk to another working virtual as a secondary disk to do the above edits.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific problem description would be nice, but to change the uuid of the harddisk use `VBoxManage internalcommands setvdiuuid disk.vdi` If your problem is that it says something like "can't register harddisk with same id" (can't exactly remember the error message) then this will help.
edit: not the answer, see comments

Comment: Just a moment i'll write errors here in a first post as an update.

Comment: I'm trying to import .vmdk into a new virtual machine on a different PC.

Comment: Do you already have a copy of that vmdk registered in vbox?

Comment: What do you mean by "registered"? I have just selected it in creation wizard of new virtual machine as a main harddisk. Should i pass through additional configuration process before starting virtual machine?

Comment: Nope, should work that way, could you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/m/88/1121/erroret.png here you go

Comment: ah, that makes things more clear, you have edit your grub config to either the new uuid or to boot from /dev/sda1 or whatever.

Comment: VBoxManage internalcommands setvdiuuid disk.vdi, but what uuid i should provide? Where to get it? As i understand, i should change the uuid of disk to match newly created virtual machine?

Comment: I have found config file of new virtual machine. There is xml document and inside it is parameter named HardDisk uuid. As i understand it should match with the uuid of virtual disk i'm trying to import. How to get uuid of the disk i'm trying to import? :)

Comment: No, that command was for changing the uuid if you happen to have the same disk twice, you have to edit your grub.conf on the vmdk to boot from whatever partition you have your system on, as the original uuid maybe has changed. Just look up how to mount a vmdk on your system and edit your grub.conf to boot from /dev/sda1 or so.

Comment: The UUID of the harddisk within the virtual machine should not have changed, so there _shouldn't_ be any reason to change grub.

Answer (score 0):

Is this added at an IDE drive or a SATA drive?  I'm guessing it's sata, and you should try changing it to IDE.